# postfix/master[1908]: warning: /usr/libexec/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling

Tags: email, postfix, configuration, master

I'm getting this error message for quite sometime and unable to find I exactly missed in the postfix mail configuration. Please see my master.cf and main.cf below.

MASTER.CF

## Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format

## of the file, see the Postfix master(5) manual page.

## ***** Unused items removed *****

## ==========================================================================

## service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args

## (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)

## ==========================================================================

smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
-o content_filter=smtp-amavis:127.0.0.1:10024
-o receive_override_options=no_address_mappings
-o content_filter=spamassassin

spamassassin      unix -      n      n      -      -      pipe
user=nobody argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
/usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}

### Enable SMTP on port 587 only for authenticated/TLS clients

submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
-o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
-o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
-o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
-o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

### Enable SMTP on port 465 only for authenticated/SSL clients

smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
-o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
-o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
-o broken_sasl_auth_clients=yes
-o content_filter=
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
-0 milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
-o content_filter=
-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp

### When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops

relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
-o fallback_relay=

## -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5

showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache

## ====================================================================

## Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual

## pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.

## ====================================================================

maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=Fq. user=foo argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient

## spam/virus section

smtp-amavis  unix  -    -       n       -       2       smtp
-o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
-o disable_dns_lookups=yes
-o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
127.0.0.1:10025 inet n  -       n       -       -       smtpd
-o content_filter=
-o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
-o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
-o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
-o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
-o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
-o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
-o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
-o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
-o smtpd_helo_required=no
-o smtpd_client_restrictions=
-o smtpd_restriction_classes=
-o disable_vrfy_command=no
-o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes

## Dovecot LDA

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=DRhu user=vmail:mail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d  ${recipient}

## Vacation mail

vacation    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
flags=Rq user=vacation argv=/usr/local/cwp/php71/bin/php -q /var/spool/vacation/vacation.php ${sender} ${recipient}

## SPF check

## policyd-spf   unix      -       n       n       -       -       spawn
user=policyd-spf argv=/usr/local/bin/policyd-spf /etc/python-policyd-spf/policyd-spf.conf

## MAIN.CF

## postfix config file

## uncomment for debugging if needed

#soft_bounce=yes

## postfix main

mail_owner = postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
delay_warning_time = 4

## postfix paths

html_directory = no
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man

## network settings

inet_interfaces = all
mydomain = microunitedbd.com
myhostname = cwp.microunitedbd.com
mynetworks = $config_directory/mynetworks
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
relay_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-relay_domains_maps.cf

## mail delivery

recipient_delimiter = +

## mappings

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
#local_recipient_maps =

## virtual setup

virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_default_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_maps.cf, regexp:/etc/postfix/virtual_regexp
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailbox_maps.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_alias_pipe_maps.cf
virtual_minimum_uid = 101
virtual_uid_maps = static:101
virtual_gid_maps = static:12
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

## debugging

debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

## authentication

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth

## tls config

smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:$data_directory/smtp_tls_session_cache

## Change mail.example.com.* to your host name

smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/hostname.key
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/hostname.crt
#smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
#smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/pki/tls/certs
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/pki/tls/certs
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = $smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers
smtp_tls_ciphers = $smtpd_tls_ciphers
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes

## rules restrictions

smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_unknown_client reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net
#smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
permit_mynetworks,
permit_sasl_authenticated,
reject_unknown_sender_domain,
reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname,
reject_unknown_client_hostname
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_whitelist, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_blacklist, reject_unauth_destination, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org, permit_dnswl_client list.dnswl.org=127.0.[0..255].[1..3], reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, check_policy_service  unix:/var/spool/postfix/postgrey/socket, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf, check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_override check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_blacklist

smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
permit_mynetworks
permit_sasl_authenticated
reject_invalid_helo_hostname
reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
reject_unknown_helo_hostname
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
unknown_address_reject_code  = 554
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 554
unknown_client_reject_code   = 554

## Other options

## email size limit ~20Meg

message_size_limit = 204800000
mailbox_size_limit = 2048000000

## Milter configuration

milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891,inet:127.0.0.1:8893,unix:/run/spamass-milter/spamass-milter.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
milter_connect_macros = j {daemon_name} v {if_name} _

## Limit 50 emails per hour per email address

anvil_rate_time_unit = 3600s
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 50

## Vacation Scripts

## vacation_destination_recipient_limit = 1
recipient_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_vacation.cf
#smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
#non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
#milter_default_action = accept
#milter_protocol = 2
tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map
#clamsmtp
content_filter = smtp-amavis:127.0.0.1:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings

Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: make sure port 25 is allowed for inbound and outbound traffic. Check in firewall settings.